# update local entry in wso2 esb via servce

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Is there any way by which, I can update local entry from esb service. I have to store a token in global variable and need to update it when it is expired. I want to keep it in local entry. Looks like I can not update it from ESB service/sequence.

```
<localEntry key="TestLocalEntry" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"><![CDATA[TestValue]]></localEntry>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you requirement is to store a global variable and not really update a local entry, you can use esb registry

Try this js to create / update an entry in governance registry (and store current payload xml in this sample) :

```
<script language="js"><![CDATA[         
    importPackage(Packages.org.apache.synapse.config);          
    mc.getConfiguration().getRegistry().newResource("gov:/trunk/test/MyEntry.xml",false);
    mc.getConfiguration().getRegistry().updateResource("gov:/trunk/test/MyEntry.xml",mc.getPayloadXML().toString());    
]]></script>
```

Try this xpath expression in your mediation to read the entry :

```
get-property('gov:/trunk/test/MyEntry.xml')
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to fix this problem with java script.

To get property value use :

```
  <script language="js"><![CDATA[var Token = mc.getEnvironment().getServerContextInformation().getProperty("TokenVal");
     mc.setProperty("TokenVal",Token);]]></script>
<property expression="$ctx:TokenVal" name="TokenValue"
        type="STRING" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
```

and to update value use:

```
 <script language="js"><![CDATA[var TokenValue = mc.getProperty("TokenValue");
        mc.getEnvironment().getServerContextInformation().addProperty("TokenVal",TokenValue);
        ]]></script>
```

but even then, I want to use registry resources if we have any in wso2 esb